# How to create SSO URL in paperlesspipeline

Tags: laravel

i am trying to create SSO URL for the paperlesspipeline, so it no needs to credential for login

i have to use laravel 5.8 and it's GuzzleHttp package

$timestamp = date(DateTime::ISO8601);
        $userID = '*****';

```
    $url = "https://dev.paperlesspipeline.com/sso/signin-v1/";

    $hash = hash_hmac('SHA256', $userID.$timestamp,secret key,false);

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['http_errors' => false]);

    $options = [
    'form_params' => [
        "USERID" => $userID,
        "timestamp" => $timestamp,
        "hash" => $hash
       ]
   ];

   $response  = $client->post($url, $options);
```

I am not get sso url, can you halp me what wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, $options);
```